# Install mysqlclient on CentOS

Tags: python, linux, django, centos, mysql-python

Hello guys I'm trying to use Django (==1.11.4) ORM on CentOS (==7.3), python 2.7.x,

So I'm trying to install python package mysqlclient (>=1.3.9)

(And not MySQL-python because the last release was on 2014-01-02)

And I got an error like this:

```
EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
```

So I found that I need to install mysql-devel RPM,
But the latest release was for CentOS 6.9:

[mysql-devel](https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/6.9/x86_64/Packages/mysql-devel-5.1.73-8.el6_8.x86_64.html)

So I found another related RPM but for CentOS 7.3, but it has the name like the old python package:

[MySQL-python](http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/7.3.1611/x86_64/Packages/MySQL-python-1.2.5-1.el7.x86_64.html)

- What should I use (Which RPM is prefered)
- If I install MySQL-python do I need the python package ?

Comment: did you find the solution ?